# Supporting Region and Language Page with proper url structure

Tags: node.js, angular, express, localization, internationalization

I been looking into implementing region and language feature for pages. Would like to get some inputs regarding proper url structuring which is scalable. App is based on nodejs, expressjs and angular2

As of now  pages url looks  like

```
app.com/vehicle/acura/model/mdx
app.com/vehicle/mazda/model/cx9
app.com/vehicle/honda/model/accord
app.com/vehicle/toyota/model/camry
```

What is the best way to add region and language support for `model` like `mdx,cx9,accord and camry` and also adding proper url structuring

```
app.com/vehicle/acura/model/mdx?lang-reg=en-US
app.com/vehicle/acura/model/en-US/mdx
app.com/vehicle/acura/model/mdx/en-US
app.com/en-US/vehicle/acura/model/mdx
```

This is my current node route

```
router.get('/vehicle/:car/model/:modelname')
```